# Can't to add data to IndexedDB where is problem in my code?

Tags: javascript, json, indexeddb

I'm trying to put object to indexedDB. But no effect.

Connection is working, and created new table "info", but when I'm trying to put data nothing happens.

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || 
window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

let db;
let request = window.indexedDB.open("InfoDB", 1);

request.onerror = function(e) {
     console.log("Klaida: " + e.target.error);
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    db = e.target.result;
    let infoTB = db.createObjectStore("info", { autoIncrement : true });
    objectStore.createIndex('data', 'data', { unique: false });
    objectStore.createIndex('laikas', 'laikas', { unique: false });
};

function getData() {
     let paketas = {
                "data": manoData,
                "laikas": {
                            manoLaikas: {
                                            "vardas": manoVardas,
                                            "telefonas": manoTelefonas,
                                            "paslauga": manoPaslauga
                                            }

                            }
                }

    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        db = e.target.result;
        let tran = db.transaction(["info"], "readwrite");
        let objektas = tran.objectStore("info");
        objektas.add(paketas);
        tran.oncomplete = function(e) {
           console.log('pavyko');
      };
}

}
```

I need that paketas content appear in info table.

Comment: When is getData called? Why is code that inserts an object located within a function called getData? The first thing I would do is move the code that connects to indexedDB to within the getData function. Bind the open request success handler immediately after calling indexedDB.open so that you will avoid various other problems.

Comment: getData is called when clicked submit button. I moved code to getData function and it worked. Now I see data in IndexedDB table. But I little confused, do I always have to write new whole code to each functions?

Comment: Um, essentially, yes, you need to write new whole code. However, you could consider writing your own function that reduces the number of times you repeat yourself, and just call it each time you need it. That is, after all, one of the main benefits of using functions.